# oData query in c#

Tags: c#, linq, odata

I am new to both odata and c# and I cannot figure out how to translate URI query like the following:

[http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers(10)/Orders](http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers%2810%29/Orders)?$expand=Order_Details

in c#, using the linq method syntax.

I tried this way:

```
var customer = context.Customers.Where( x => x.Id == 10 ).First();

foreach(var order in customer.Orders.Expand("Order_Details")){
    //stuff
}
```

But customer.Orders does not have the "Expand" method. 
How do I deal with these queries where I have to expand a navigation property connected to a specific entity?

Comment: Add the [proper using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679728(v=vs.110).aspx): `using System.Data.Services.Client;`.

Comment: The problem is that I can actually use Expand method with Customers:
`var orders = context.Customers.Expand("Orders")`
is correct, but this results in this query:

`http://services.odata.org/Nortwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$expand=Orders`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your code cannot compile. `x => c.Id == 10` is wrong; also there is a closing paranthesis on your foreach missing.
Second, you need to include Orders in your customer variable to do this.

I am using this Northwind v3 service to demonstrate this (http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/) as well as LinqPad (www.linqpad.net)

```
var customer = Customers.Expand("Orders/Order_Details")
                        .Where(cus => cus.CustomerID == "ALFKI");

foreach (var element in customer)
{
    element.Orders.Dump();
}
```

This results in an URL call like this one:

```
http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers('ALFKI')?$expand=Orders/Order_Details
```

Output:

[image]

[Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAy10.jpg)

**//EDIT**
Based on the comments below. If you do not want to go over the customer table and expand orders AND order_details, you can do it like this as well:

```
var orders = Orders.Expand("Order_Details")
                   .Where(o => o.CustomerID == "ALFKI").Dump();
```

OR

```
var orders = Orders.Expand(ex => ex.Order_Details)
                   .Where(o => o.CustomerID == "ALFKI").Dump();
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the syntax errors, but I was not pasting my code. With the example I just wrote it works, but in my case is not working (northwind was just a similar case).

Comment: What if I don't want to expand the customer, but I just need Order and Order Details? With the query you wrote we are getting information of Order and Order Details inline with the data of the customer, instead with:

`http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers('ALFKI')/Orders?$expand=Order_Details`

we get only the 'needed' info.

Comment: I was basing my example just on your case, because you went the same way with customer -> order -> orderdetail. I only wanted to demonstrate how it basicly works.

Comment: Sure and that helped a lot. But how would you convert in c# the query I wrote in the previous comment?(so, without expanding customer but expanding its orders)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to request for all the child properties you need as part of the OData query itself.

try following

```
context.Customers.Expand("Orders/Order_Details").Where(c => x => c.Id == 10 ).First();
foreach(var order in customer.Orders){
    //stuff
}
```